# Vertical collapsing three divs angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have three divs(panels) on one page. In two panels there are tables and when i open that page on smaller display it breaks design. So i wonder is it possible to add some button on panels for collapsing so that user can collapse panels that he doesn't need when open page on smaller display.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="hpanel hblue">
            <div class="panel-heading" translate>
                Factory
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">

                <img file-url="logo" thumbnail="true" class="img-logo" ng-show="logo"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="hpanel hblue">
            <div class="panel-heading" translate>
                Factory centers
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" ng-table="centersTable">

                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="hpanel hblue">
                    <div class="panel-heading" translate>
                        Factory services
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover nowrap" ng-table="servicesTable">

                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

It would be great if that button could be in panel-heading on right place and when user click on it it hide that panel and if it click again it open panel.
I was looking something on internet but i couldn't find anzthing that could help me. 
P.S. I'm using AngularJS if that is important for this.
Could someone pls help me with this problem ?

Comment: It looks like you are also using Bootstrap library? If so you could use the Collapse  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/

Comment: @Michael yes, bit this is for horizontal collapse, a need vertical collapse, when i click it move panel to the left side

Answer (score 1):

I am including tr tag and td tag inside the table tag

also adding CSS(margin-top or margin-bottom) for the respetive Div

you can check below code

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function() {

});
```

```css
table, th , td  {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.marginTop{
margin-top:25px;
}
.marginBottom{
margin-bottom:25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="hpanel hblue">
                    <div class="panel-heading" translate>
                        Factory
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <img file-url="logo" thumbnail="true" class="img-logo" ng-show="logo" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 marginTop">
                <div class="hpanel hblue">
                    <div class="panel-heading" translate>
                        Factory centers
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover nowrap" ng-table="servicesTable">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>your table1 data1</td>
                                    <td><button>button1</button></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>your table1 data2</td>
                                    <td><button>button2</button></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>your table1 data3</td>
                                    <td><button>button3</button></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 marginTop">
                <div class="hpanel hblue">
                    <div class="panel-heading" translate>
                        Factory services
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover nowrap" ng-table="servicesTable">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>your table2 data1</td>
                                    <td><button>button1</button></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>your table2 data2</td>
                                    <td><button>button2</button></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>your table2 data3</td>
                                    <td><button>button3</button></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```